# Build my first app with Android Studio

Tags: android, mobile, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio to build my first app, wich is a mobile game.

Actually, the structure is very simple. Like that :

- MyGame

  - assets

    - css
    - js
    - img
    - sound
  - game.html

In Android Studio, i've seen that all my files must are on the src directory, that's right.

But when i'm running my app, I don't know how can i run directly to my "game.html" file.

With probably default parameter, it's running

```
activity_main.xml
```

.

And when i'm trying to make my layout activity_main with HTML content, it doesn't work..

Comment: Unless you have substantial Android development experience, I do not recommend the use of Android Studio during its "early preview" release.

Comment: I support the opinion of CommonsWare. Try first with the Eclipse plugin Android SDK. Android Studio has many problems, so to say. Either way, is your game html based? Can you just open a webView and open the game.html inside of it, if it's not written explicitly for Android?

Answer (score 1):

Click on "Project", select "Packages" > layout > activity_main.xml.

Like this:

[image: screenshot]